# Read xml with repeat elements using xdocument

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

i need to xml file repeated item. Inside "item" i have fields like title, pubdate, description, dc:creator and with repeatwp:comment... see the xml file below..

```
<channel>
    <item>
        <title>What Messed With My Head: Summit 2011</title>
        <link>http://www.wcablog.com/2011/08/what-messed-with-my-head-summit-2011/</link>
        <pubDate>Fri, 26 Aug 2011 09:10:04 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator>willowcreekassociation</dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.wcablog.com/?p=1706</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded>
            <![CDATA[text here]]>
        </content:encoded>
        <wp:comment>
            <wp:comment_id>1016</wp:comment_id>
            <wp:comment_author><![CDATA[]]></wp:comment_author>
            <wp:comment_author_email>thelmabowlen@gmail.com</wp:comment_author_email>
            <wp:comment_author_url></wp:comment_author_url>
            <wp:comment_author_IP></wp:comment_author_IP>
            <wp:comment_date>2011-08-26 20:13:00</wp:comment_date>
            <wp:comment_content><![CDATA[some text ]]></wp:comment_content>
        </wp:comment>
        <wp:comment>
            <wp:comment_id>1016</wp:comment_id>
            <wp:comment_author><![CDATA[]]></wp:comment_author>
            <wp:comment_author_email>thelmabowlen@gmail.com</wp:comment_author_email>
            <wp:comment_author_url></wp:comment_author_url>
            <wp:comment_author_IP></wp:comment_author_IP>
            <wp:comment_date>2011-08-26 20:13:00</wp:comment_date>
            <wp:comment_content><![CDATA[some text ]]></wp:comment_content>
        </wp:comment>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>What Messed With My Head: Summit 2011</title>
        <link>http://www.wcablog.com/2011/08/what-messed-with-my-head-summit-2011/</link>
        <pubDate>Fri, 26 Aug 2011 09:10:04 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator>willowcreekassociation</dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.wcablog.com/?p=1706</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded>
            <![CDATA[text here]]>
        </content:encoded>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>What Messed With My Head: Summit 2011</title>
        <link>http://www.wcablog.com/2011/08/what-messed-with-my-head-summit-2011/</link>
        <pubDate>Fri, 26 Aug 2011 09:10:04 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator>willowcreekassociation</dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.wcablog.com/?p=1706</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded>
            <![CDATA[text here]]>
        </content:encoded>
        <wp:comment></wp:comment>
        <wp:comment></wp:comment>
    </item>
</channel>
```

I am using following code to read xml..

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("willowcreekassociationblog.wordpress.xml");

        var list = xDoc.Descendants("Occurrence")
        .Select(o => new List.XMLList
        {
            title = (string)o.Element("title"),
            URL = (string)o.Element("link"),
            Descr = (string)o.Element("Description"),
            StartDate = (DateTime)o.Element("pubdate"),
        })
        .ToList();
```

But i dont know how read the wp:comment with my above code...can anyone help me how to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said what you want to do with the data, which makes the question hard to answer. You also haven't shown where the `wp` namespace alias is defined, but hey...

You want *something* like this, within your `Select` call:

```
Comments = o.Elements(wp + "comment")
            .Select(comment => Comment.FromXElement(comment))
            .ToList();
```

I find it helpful to give static methods within the domain objects which can perform the transformation from `XElement` - it keeps things clearer.

`FromXElement` would then be something like:

```
public static Comment FromXElement(XElement x)
{
    return new Comment((int) x.Element(wp + "comment_id"),
                       (string) x.Element(wp + "author"),
                       ...);
}
```

Comment: i just need to read the data and assign it to a list..and save the data into database..

Comment: @Srav: Well I was assuming you already had a type to represent the comment, in the same way that you've got a type to represent the item.